# #2006 Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста что это за ошибка - #2006 Невозможно подключиться к серверу MySQL. Выходит она при входе через phpmyadmin, после того как ввиду логин и пароль. Сервер установлен локально. Ошибку эту начало выдавать после того как я импортировал в WP xml файл который прилагался к шаблону  ( демо контент ). В этих делах просто я новичок-любитель, просто появился интерес как это исправить. Заранее благодарен!!!

Answer (score 1):

Логин/пароль сверьте или смените.

если linux, то попробуйте

```
cat /root/.my.cnf
```

Там может лежать пароль к пользователю *root*.